# App should only run on iPhone

Tags: iphone, app-store

We have successfully uploaded our app on appstore & now its ready for sale & listed in itunes. 
But the problem is its displaying that it will run on iphone / ipad / ipod as well,
Where as our app should run only on iphone.

We have checked the info.plist file & there its showing targeted device family as iPhone.

Edit 1: Our app needs to send sms. So, we dont want our app to run on devices which cant send 
SMS.

Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: What's wrong with it running on an iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every iPhone app must run on the iPad.
If it doesn't say "Universal" then you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally every application should run on iPad but while submitting the application you can also set the target device family in iTunes Connect. Please  visit your iTunes Connect portal.

Comment: Yes, it will run on both but can't I restrict my app only to iPhone. My app is alredy in AppStore, now How can I change target device family.

Comment: In that case you need to update your application and put it for review again.

Comment: I didnt get that 'run only on iphone' option. Can't I do it in my infoplist file

Answer (score 1):

Apple's guidelines may say that they will reject iPhone apps that don't run on an iPad in 1x/2x compatibility mode.